# How to add padding to UITableViewCell textLabel?

Tags: uitableview, uikit

I have a cell with text, and there is no padding if its German (or some other language with verrrry long words). How do I add padding to the textLabel while using auto height layout in the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Best way I found so far is to active top and bottom anchors like this

```
self.textLabel?.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10.0).isActive = true
```

This actually is adding padding of 5.0 above and bellow the textLabel in case of default style UITableViewCell